Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?
This answer contains a typo in line 2: it says $a = aG$ whereas this should be $\alpha = aG$. I tried to correct it but the system does not let me and displays: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"
I don't see anything else in the post that warrants attention, yet this is an egregious error. What can be done?

Small help; use <--! --> that is inline comment :)

I've heavily edited the answer by the way. Nice catch that I've missed...

If you have enough reputation you can comment below the question, hoping that somebody with high enough rep or the original author edits the answer. You can ask in chat if somebody is willing to help, no reputation required for chat. Or you can, as suggested, create an edit with a comment in it or any other non-displayable content. Make sure to explain that in the why and how in the edit comment though.
The problem with the current system is that it cannot detect if changes are significant; it just assumes that they aren't if there are too few characters changed. That doesn't work on formulas of course. The reason for this is to avoid having to review each and every insignificant comment in the review queue.
